# Retain the previous cell value and copy over to next cells python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

When ever the data has category B and the next row also contains Category B, then the value of the first cell should be copied over to the next cell. The formula to be applied only on Category B.

here the column Value shows the original value and the Expected column shows what value to be expected. I tried using shift command but it is of not use when it comes to retain the value.

My database is very big, attached is just the sample.

'''
Code Tried '''

```
df['expected'] = df.groupby('category')['value'].transform('first')
```

The above code is copying the value 20 at all the places for category B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split every continous of `B` into groupID `s` and groupby `s` with `Category`

```
s = df.Category.ne('B').cumsum()
df['New_val'] = df.groupby(['Category', s])['Value'].transform('first')

Out[23]:
   Time Category  Value  New_val
0  9:00        A     50       50
1  9:01        A     50       50
2  9:02        B     20       20
3  9:03        B     30       20
4  9:04        C     40       40
5  9:05        B     25       25
6  9:06        B     30       25
7  9:07        B     35       25
8  9:08        D     50       50
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numpy method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":list("AABBCBBBD"),"Data":[50,50,20,30,40,25,30,35,50]})                     
# create result column
df["Modified"] = df["Data"]
# get underlying numpy array
data = df["Modified"].to_numpy()
# get mask of B positions
B = df["Category"].to_numpy()=="B"
# find on and off indices
dB, = np.where(np.diff(B, prepend=False, append=False))
# repeat the first element of each block len(block) times and fill them
# in according to the mask
data[B] = data[dB[::2]].repeat(dB[1::2]-dB[::2])

# admire
df
#  Category  Data  Modified
# 0        A    50        50
# 1        A    50        50
# 2        B    20        20
# 3        B    30        20
# 4        C    40        40
# 5        B    25        25
# 6        B    30        25
# 7        B    35        25
# 8        D    50        50
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul ...the solution works perfectly. Based on your answer, I felt, I still have to explore the strength of numpy...my basics are weak for now...Really appreciate the methodology.