# How to shift the columns in a Python Pandas dataframe only when the bottom element is nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

below is a screenshot of the dataframe documenting gross margin of several listed companies in several days.

My goal is to shift down the specific column down by 1 if its bottom element is `nan` and do nothing if the bottom element is not `nan`. I tried to use a for loop but it did not work. All suggestions are appreciated. :)

[image: Screenshot of the dataframe]

Solved! Thanks @11574713 for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you shift a column down, then the top cell of that column will be `nan`.

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685307/retain-the-previous-cell-value-and-copy-over-to-next-cells-python-pandas-datafra

Comment: @Azhar Khan Yeah that's the goal, after such manipulation the bottom row may reflect the latest information, the second bottom row may reflect the second latest info,...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be quite similar... My above requirements seem to be way too complex for .map() .zip() and .apply(lambda x: x) functions. Plus the for loop seems to be very useless in such iteration. The loop changes nothing in the df in the end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if pd.isna(your_df['your_col'].iloc[-1]):
    your_df['your_col'] = your_df['your_col'].shift()
```

To loop through and do for all columns:

```
for col in your_df.columns:
    if pd.isna(your_df[col].iloc[-1]):
        your_df[col] = your_df[col].shift()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. :) May I ask if I desire to apply such method to all columns should I simply put it in a for loop, then in this case what will be the method to call different columns...?

Comment: Yes that works.

Will update answer.